# Pushing Pycharm Project To Git : Multiple Root Content

Tags: git, github, pycharm

My flask application on Pycharm requires python functions from another Pycharm project. To accomplish that I went to project structure and added the required project as a part of the Root Content.

Now when I push to Git, it only pushes the newly added project. I think Pycharm only recognizes the newly added root content and fails to recognize the actual flask project.

What can I do to ensure Pycharm pushes the entire project? [using VCS on Pycharm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's bad idea to mix your projects this way.
Try using git submodules: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules.

Comment: i have actually made changes to the newly imported project. i want to package this as one project now to git. any idea how i can achieve that?

Comment: You have two way. The first, you have and manage two separate projects. The second, just merge content of your projects but delete `.git` dir from second projects for pycharm not being confused.